# Can you set up a reverse proxy to forward requests based on request content and/or parameters?

Tags: php, http, reverse-proxy, https, apache-2.4

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy that forwards requests to different servers based on content in the body of the request itself.

For example, if the request has a parameter 'type' = 'A', I'd like to forward the request to server A; if 'type' = 'B', to server B; etc.

We currently run Apache (and PHP, if that helps) and I understand that Apache's mod_proxy supports forwarding requests based on parameters in the request URL, but I haven't found anything on how to forward requests based on parameters in the body.

We'd love to stick with Apache for our reverse proxy but are also open to other options.  Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Do you mean parameters in the HTTP headers, or the POST content, or the URL query string?

Comment: To me it looks like the question is about POST content. Not at least URL query string, third chapter tells that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion--I meant POST content, not HTTP headers or URL query string.